# How to determine the set that satisfies $\{p \in [0, \infty] : f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\lambda) \}$

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

I have to determine the set which satisfies $\{p \in [0, \infty] : f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\lambda) \}$ for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} \ \  & \text{if} \ x \in (0,1] \\
0 \ \ & \text{if} \ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1]
\end{cases} $$

I have looked at three different cases, i.e. $p = 0, p = (0, \infty)$ and $p = \infty$ where the last case is troubling me.

If $p = \infty$ we have to check that $f \in \mathcal{L}^\infty$. So assume that this is the case. Then by definition there $\exists R > 0$ such that $|f| < R$. We have that
$$ |f| < R \Leftrightarrow \left| \frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac{1}{x} < R \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{R} < x \Leftrightarrow x \in \left(\frac{1}{R}, 1\right]$$

but how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$ so $f \notin L^\infty$. There is no such that as $L^0$. For $p \in (0,\infty)$ and $p \neq 1$, we see that:
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|^p \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{1}{1 - p}x^{1 - p}\right]_{0^+}^1 = 1 - \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^{1 - p}}{1 - p}
$$
RHS is finite iff $p < 1$. Finally, for $p = 1$, we have:
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[\ln(x)\right]_{0^+}^1 = -\infty
$$
Thus, for $p \in (0,\infty]$, we have:
$$
f \in L^p \iff p \in (0,1)
$$
(Note that while $L^p$ is well-defined for $0 < p < 1$, they are not normed spaces as $\|\cdot\|_p$ does not respect triangle inequality, and so are in general not studied)

Comment: But how do I show that $f \notin \mathcal{L}^\infty$ given the definition in my book, i.e. $\exists R > 0 : |f| < R $.

Comment: The negation is $\forall R > 0 \exists x \in \mathbb{R}[|f(x)| \geq R]$. For any $R$, choose $x = \frac{1}{R}$.